# Is it possible to only use lock and condition to get ABCABC result

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to get the result like this, **ABCABCABCABCABC**. I have already implemented it by using a flag to indict the current print state. However, I think I can remove the flag to implement the same function. But after my modification, the code is blocked in the construct of AlternateDemo. I could not find the root cause. Could anyone tell me the reason?

My code is below.

**NOTE**: thread-A is like A, thread-B is like B, and thread-C is like C

```
package edu.seu.juc.problem;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TestABCAlternateOnlyCondition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlternateDemo demo = new AlternateDemo();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopA(i);
            }
        }, "thread-A").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopB(i);
            }
        }, "thread-B").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopC(i);
            }

            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        }, "thread-C").start();
    }


    private static class AlternateDemo {
        private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        private Condition conditionA = lock.newCondition();
        private Condition conditionB = lock.newCondition();
        private Condition conditionC = lock.newCondition();

        public AlternateDemo() {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                conditionB.await();
                conditionC.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void loopA(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                conditionA.await();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                conditionB.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void loopB(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {

                conditionB.await();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                conditionC.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void loopC(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                conditionC.await();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                conditionA.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIUC it would be stuck at `conditionB.await()`, because at that point nothing exists that would signal `conditionB`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have confused the conception of `Condition` and `PV`(`Semaphore` in JAVA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add a flag to control thread to be awaited.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TestABCAlternateOnlyCondition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlternateDemo demo = new AlternateDemo();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopA(i);
            }
        }, "thread-A").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopB(i);
            }
        }, "thread-B").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopC(i);
            }

            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        }, "thread-C").start();
    }


    private static class AlternateDemo {
        private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        private Condition conditionA = lock.newCondition();
        private Condition conditionB = lock.newCondition();
        private Condition conditionC = lock.newCondition();
        private static int nextThread = 1; // control thread to await


        public void loopA(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                while (nextThread != 1) {
                    conditionA.await();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }
                nextThread = 2;
                conditionB.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void loopB(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {

                while (nextThread != 2) {
                    conditionB.await();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }
                nextThread = 3;
                conditionC.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void loopC(int totalLoop) {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                while (nextThread != 3) {
                    conditionC.await();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }
                nextThread = 1;
                conditionA.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my first solution using a flag as I said above. I try to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints from @root. Now, I can solve the problem by only using the semaphore.

The code is below,

```
package edu.seu.juc.problem;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

/**
 * @author: zs.sun
 * Create at: 2020/5/25 8:59
 * @Package: edu.seu.juc.problem
 * @ProjectName: af-study
 * @Description:
 */
public class TestABCAlternateOnlyCondition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlternateDemo demo = new AlternateDemo();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopA(i);
            }
        }, "thread-A").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopB(i);
            }
        }, "thread-B").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                demo.loopC(i);
            }

            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        }, "thread-C").start();
    }


    private static class AlternateDemo {
        private Semaphore semaphoreA = new Semaphore(1);
        private Semaphore semaphoreB = new Semaphore(1);
        private Semaphore semaphoreC = new Semaphore(1);

        public AlternateDemo() {
            try {
                // NOTE: init the status at the beginning
                semaphoreB.acquire();
                semaphoreC.acquire();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void loopA(int totalLoop) {

            try {
                semaphoreA.acquire();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                semaphoreB.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void loopB(int totalLoop) {
            try {

                semaphoreB.acquire();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                semaphoreC.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void loopC(int totalLoop) {

            try {
                semaphoreC.acquire();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + totalLoop);
                }

                semaphoreA.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this? [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Abra Thank you for your hint. I have forgotten this page. I will note this next time. When I ask this problem, I truly do not know the root cause. And **@root** give me inspiration to find the reason. Then I write my answer.